# Assigning a task to a team

Tags: activecollab

I'd like to assigne a task to a whole team of users, instead of a single user. Then anybody of that team should be able to execute the task. I do run the self hosted version of activecollab.

For example:

1. My team has 10 members, and therefore a capacity of 10* 8h/day = 80h
2. I'm assigning 100h of work/tasks to that team --> 80h stay for the day, 20h get pushed to the next day
3. Any member of that team can grab a task, track time and finally finish it.

Is that something which can be done right now via the api?
If not, is sth. like that on the roadmap?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveCollab does not support task assignment to a team, only to an individual user. API can't be used to work around assignment of a single task to a single user. What you can do is implement a routine that will create a copy of a task for each team member and assign it to a member, but that can easily clutter your projects.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick response.
Then I'm continuing with my workaround:

1. I'm getting the workload from all users and store them in a seperate table.
2. When I distribute the tasks, I look this table up, and see who is available for that activity, and finally assigne that task to that user.
3. Under /workload the users can still reassign and reschedule, I'll run the sync from 1. from time to time
4. E/thing else can be also done via the frontend

Comment: What you describe is the pull workflow and also something we want to use. I have another workaround for you @Andy Hemmerich: Create a proxy user (e.g. "Team Frontend"). This user has a capacity of 80h. That way time sheets and workload will still work.
However you would probably still need a custom API interface to allow people to easily pick tasks and reassign them. Something we are hopefully able to work on.